# Are there any XACML evaluation engine implementations?

Tags: ide, implementation, sourceforge, xacml, xacml3

I have to evaluate XACML policies as a part of my research. I am looking for an IDE for xacml evaluation. Can anyone suggest one?

I have installed wso2 identity server but when I am uploading a policy its giving an error that the policy can't be uploaded.

I also downloaded UMU-Xacml-Editor. Can any one tell me how to use that editor for evaluation?

I have even downloaded several source forge engines, But I am not able to install them. can anyone kindly let me know the installation details

Can you even let me know if there are any open tools for evaluating xacml policies.

Thanks & Regards,
Pavani.

Answer (score 2):

What is identity server version that you are using? In Identity Server (V 4.0.0), when you upload a policy, it would do schema validation.  If your policy is not according to the schema, policy uploading would be failed.

However you can disable policy schema validation by setting following property to "false" in entitlement.properties file which can be found at /repository/conf/security

PDP.SchemaValidation.Enable=false

Also you can simply create policy with WSO2 Identity Server policy editor UI. I guess this blog post [1] may be useful. But it has been written for Version 3.2.3.  May not be valid for 4.0.0. version

Sorry. I have not used UMU-Xacml-Editor.

[1] http://xacmlinfo.com/2012/05/02/xacml-policy-editor-in-wso2-identity-server/

Comment: You can find new policy creation UI from here http://xacmlinfo.org/2013/09/02/how-write-xacml-policies-1/